# Confused in setting steps_per_epoch using image data generator

Tags: image, keras

I have some confusion with steps_per_epoch. Any clarification is appreciated.

I read that steps_per_epoch is normally set to `number of samples/batch size`. However, I am following this tutorial https://medium.com/the-owl/k-fold-cross-validation-in-keras-3ec4a3a00538
that uses `train_data_generator=idg.flow_from_dataframe()`.

Am I correct in setting steps_per_epoch to be `len(train_data_generator)/32` instead of `len(training_data)/32`.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: No, it is not correct, what is the source of this confusion?

Comment: I should have use train_data_generator instead of the above. Thank you for your comment.